# Page not reloading after print the window with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey I don't know why my page is not reloading without cache after using `window.print()` . the window is reloading when i am typing `window.location.reload(true)` on browser console but not working after printing . I've try but can't figure-out why this is not working here.

```
$('#print_report').click(function(){
      $('body').html($('#cashReport').html());
      window.print();
      return window.location.reload(true);
});
```

Comment: Try without "return". Just - 

window.location.reload();

Comment: I've tried @Alicelf  but not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can reload the page after the print process finishes.You can listen for the after print event using `window.onafterprint`

```
$('#print_report').click(function(){
      $('body').html($('#cashReport').html());
      window.print();
});

 window.onafterprint = function(){
      window.location.reload(true);
 }
```

Comment: Or `$(window).on('afterprint', function () { ... })` for consistency

Comment: yes that's work but when i'am clicking save as pdf then this is not working. how can i solve it also any idea.

Comment: what do you want to do on save as pdf??

Answer (score 3):

It might be too late but I got to this issue and none of the solutions worked when using Print to PDF and some real printers also, I found the solution using:

```
           setInterval(function(){
              window.location.reload(true);
           }, 200);
           window.print();
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the afterprint event. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onafterprint

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.href = window.location.href  ;
```

Comment: This answer isn't that helpful. Can you add more information about why this would work? Offhand, I don't see why this would change anything.

Comment: try this line just after window.print(); ... hope that it ll be helpful ..

Answer (score -1):

you can use this javascript function  and call it after print

```
   <script>
    function refreshParent() {
        window.opener.location.reload(true);
    }
   </script>
```

Comment: thanks i think this will not solve my problem . i already get the solution